# meaning of 把自己 and 收下 and 在地里 and some translations

Tags: translation

i am learning new i have a couple of questions about a text
1：收完白菜，老山羊把自己种的白菜送给他们
2：山羊收下白菜
1:what 收完 exactly is translated into-what about 把自己 can you tell me the grammar and exact translation 
2:what exactly 收下 mean?
please explain the grammar of themif any
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`收` means (among other things) `to harvest`
`完` is used to indicate that the `action is completed`, finished. So
`收完` means `to finish the harvest`, or as @倪阔乐 put it, to complete the harvest

Similarly `说完` means to finish what you want to say. `说完了没有？` "Is that all you have to say/Are you finished (talking)?". Grammar books usually discuss this `完` verb complement, so try to use them.

`把` is another particle you have to look into. If used, the sentence order is changed. The object of action follows immediately after this particle, thus it gets more emphasis. Consider e.g.

`我在吃午饭。` `I am having lunch.` 
`我把午饭已经吃完了。` `I have finished eating my lunch.` (Just to use the `完` again in combination with `把`). Notice that `午饭` is pushed to the left of the sentence. This is an important particle and sentence structure that you have to understand. Again, consult your textbook or grammar reference for more.

As for `收下`, it simply means `to receive` or `to accept`. E.g. `收下名片` to receive a business card or `请收下这个`... Please accept this..., `收下礼物` to receive gifts/presents.

Here's one more example sentence that uses `把` and `收下`:

`请把它作为一件礼物收下。` `Please accept it as a gift.`

`把` is immediatelly followed by the object `它` (it)
`一件礼物` a gift (one piece of gift, I hope you know what a classifier is)
`作为` as ...
`收下` accept

Answer (score 1):

收完: complete harvest
收下: receive